# Groovy NullPointerException on "gradle appRun"

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, nullpointerexception

I am trying to run the plain [Java Auth0 starter](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java/01-login?download=true) which is a `gradle` app started with `./gradlew clean appRun`.

I'm receiving the error which is certainly `groovy` related:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getText() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
```

Before this I've received the warnings:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/xijinping/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.4.11/52a60df8b4cbfe39469171a42ca77a3e4eb4e737/groovy-2.4.11.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I'm running Java 13:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 13 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
$ javac --version
javac 13
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug on my side or something to do with `gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm running Java 13

Well, that's the problem. The quickstart build with Gradle 3.3 (see [gradle-wrapper.properties](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-servlet-sample/blob/master/01-Login/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L6) on GitHub). Java 13 support has been added to Gradle with the 6.0 release ([Gradle 6.0 Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/release-notes.html#support-for-java-13)).

The quickstart samples are intended to be run with Java 8.